# Download link inside iFrame works in Chrome, but not in Electron

Tags: html, electron, ptc-windchill

I have built an Electron application which downloads files from Sharepoint. This works flawlessly. Soon the files will be transferred to Windchill and only be available there. When I substitute the download link with the link from Windchill, it doesn't work, although the link works inside the browser.

My app loads the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="de" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>

    <main class="main_window">
      <iframe  src="example.html"  ></iframe>
    </main>

   </body>
</html>
```

which then loads the example.html into an iFrame

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="de" dir="ltr"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


    </head><body>
    <main>
       <a href="https://sharepoint.com/sites/example.docx">SharePoint link</a>
       <a href="https://www.windchill.plm.com/Windchill/servlet/AttachmentsDownloadDirectionServlet?oid=OR:wt.doc.WTDocument:888888888;oid=OR:wt.content.ApplicationData:99999999999;role=PRIMARY">Windchill link</a>
    </main>

   </body>
</html>
```

When I click the SharePoint link, the download starts, but when I click the Windchill link, nothing happens. In Chrome I get redirected a few times, when I click the Windchill link. Does maybe this redirection not work in iFrames? If yes, what simple embedding alternatives to iFrames do I have? I already tried

```
   <object  src="example.html"  ></object>
   <embed  src="example.html"  ></embed>
```

both with the same result.

Comment: Well, unfortunately I can't download the files from the main process or at least I wouldn't know how. I have several HTML files that contain the links. Isn't there a way to force calling getURL anyhow?

Comment: There is no download link unfortunately. Is there another way with a javascript function? This functionality is crucial for my app. I mean if Chrome can do it, why shouldn't Electron be able to?

Comment: @Rhayene Can you please explain me why this doesn't work and would work with the Electron.net API?

Comment: @Rhayene I think the download would work work without the Electron.net API, if I had a direct link to the file. Can you think of any other solution? I mean it must be possible, if it is possible in Chrome. Is it maybe possble to pass the link to Chrome and then get it back? I don't even understand why it doesn't work

Comment: Well, it is impossible to give you access to my Windchill account. Since I don't understand what is not working, it is hard to come up with a link that excites the same behaviour :(

Comment: @Rhayene When I open the link directly in main.js via window.loadURL(windchill_link), it works. I don't understand what is going on here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200896/discussion-between-rhayene-and-neolith).